Does the Outlet rerender with the parent component in React JS?
I have useWindowSize hook that triggers each time when the window is resized so the MainWrapper component rerenders many times. But the Outlet element is not rerendered. Is that allright?
Are there any documentation links to that?
const MainWrapper = () => {
  useWindowSize();

  return (
    <Layout className={styles.layout} hasSider>
      <Sider />
      <Layout className={styles.container}>
        <Layout.Content id="layoutContentRoot">
          <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
            <Outlet />
          </Suspense>
        </Layout.Content>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};
export default MainWrapper;


As far as documentation goes I could only find a bare minimum on API usage:
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet
Searching through the source code for Outlet related files in the react-router repo, there isn't a usage of React.memo, only some useMemo hooks which may prevent rerenders, so I would assume it's by the design of the library.
However if you want a rerender to happen, you could modify your useWindowSize  hook so it would return reactive value that will change on window size change and use it as key prop for you Outlet component, e.g.:
const MainWrapper = () => {
  const size = useWindowSize();

  return (
    <Layout className={styles.layout} hasSider>
      <Sider />
      <Layout className={styles.container}>
        <Layout.Content id="layoutContentRoot">
          <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
            <Outlet key={size} />
          </Suspense>
        </Layout.Content>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
};

Note: Also you might be using for React.memo in your application may be for the route component that prevents from rerender :)
Related links in react-router source code:
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx
